# SVR ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,9)

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I am using SVR to predict NBA fantasy scores.  My indep variables add to my dep variable.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

## X is an array of 58 rows by 9 columns.  The sum of the 9 columns = the 10th column (Y)

```
DK = pd.read_csv('NV.csv')
X = DK.iloc[:, :-1].values.astype(float)
Y = DK.iloc[:,9].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)


#Feature Scaling

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
Y = sc_y.fit_transform(Y)

#Fitting SVR to data and creating regressors

from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor1 = SVR(kernel='rbf')
regressor1.fit(X,Y)
```

### When I run the above, I get a data warning and the following output

```
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the         shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1, gamma='auto',
kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

---

Predicting a new result is where my code runs into a road block

```
y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform((regressor1.predict(sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]])))))
```

This returns the below error.  Is the issue how I fit / scaled the data or something completely different?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-9c7f8b557a70> in <module>
----> 1 y_pred = sc_y.inverse_transform((regressor1.predict(sc_X.transform(np.array([[1.9]])))))

~\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in transform(self, X, copy)
767         else:
768             if self.with_mean:
--> 769                 X -= self.mean_
770             if self.with_std:
771                 X /= self.scale_

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,9)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+ValueError%3A+non-broadcastable+output+operand+with+shape

Comment: I'm also slightly confused as to why you are using machine learning to predict a calculated measure that you created.

Answer (score 0):

First to understand the error itself:

```
X -= self.mean_
```

I can reproduce the error with:

```
In [234]: X = np.array([[1.23]])                                                                       
In [235]: X.shape                                                                                      
Out[235]: (1, 1)
In [236]: X -= np.array([[1,2,3]])                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-236-6854fd7cd554> in <module>
----> 1 X -= np.array([[1,2,3]])

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,3)
```

I was going write that working back up the traceback to your own code could take some work.  But I see your own code:

```
sc_X.transform(np.array([[6.5]]))
```

`np.array([[6.5]])` is most likely the (1,1) array, `X`.